# Simplify ratios inside of container

Tags: c++, c++17

Suppose you are given a container of ratios and you want to simplify the ratios to the lowest integers.

Input:

```
std::vector<int> v1 = { 10, 20 , 30, 40 };
```

Output:

```
1,2,3,4
```

How does one solve this for n-sized container? I am looking for general solution, that works for any number of elements and any integer values.

Comment: Look for the greatest common divisor and divide all of them.

Comment: ratios are 10/20 and 30/40 or how do the numbers relate to each other?

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us a little about why you need to do this? I am finding it hard to imagine a use for this operation!

Answer (score 7):

Repeatedly apply `std::gcd` to all numbers in the vector to find the gcd of all the numbers then divide every element by the gcd.

```
const int gcd = std::reduce(v1.cbegin(), v1.cend(), 1, [](int a, int b) {
  return std::gcd(a, b);
});
if (gcd != 1) {
  for (int &elem : v1) {
    elem /= gcd;
  }
}
```

Comment: Minor improvement: insert `for` loop under `if (gcd != 1)`, what can easly happen if any value is prime number.